Get the attention scores of a pretrained transformer in pytorch
I've been trying to look at the attention scores of a pretrained transformer when I pass specific data in. It's specifically a Pytorch Transformer. I've tried using forward hooks, but I'm only able to get the final output of attention modules when what I want is NxN matrices of attention scores (softmax(QxK). I also would really prefer to do this via pytorch code and not use outside tools such as BertViz.
Does anyone know if there's a way to do this?

You can navigate into the PyTorch source code for torch.nn.Transformer, where the attention is implemented through the MultiheadAttention module.
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html#torch.nn.MultiheadAttention
In the forward pass, the MultiheadAttention module calls the multi_head_attention_forward function. This function handles several operations, such as the QKVO linear projections and the attention mechanism itself.
The attention calculation can be found at the following line in the PyTorch codebase:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/nn/functional.py#L6238
B, Nt, E = q.shape
q_scaled = q * math.sqrt(1.0 / float(E))

assert not (
    is_causal and attn_mask is None
), "FIXME: is_causal not implemented for need_weights"

if attn_mask is not None:
    attn_output_weights = torch.baddbmm(
        attn_mask, q_scaled, k.transpose(-2, -1)
    )
else:
    attn_output_weights = torch.bmm(q_scaled, k.transpose(-2, -1))
attn_output_weights = softmax(attn_output_weights, dim=-1)
if dropout_p > 0.0:
    attn_output_weights = dropout(attn_output_weights, p=dropout_p)

attn_output = torch.bmm(attn_output_weights, v)

attn_output = (
    attn_output.transpose(0, 1).contiguous().view(tgt_len * bsz, embed_dim)
)
attn_output = linear(attn_output, out_proj_weight, out_proj_bias)
attn_output = attn_output.view(tgt_len, bsz, attn_output.size(1))

# optionally average attention weights over heads
attn_output_weights = attn_output_weights.view(bsz, num_heads, tgt_len, src_len)
if average_attn_weights:
    attn_output_weights = attn_output_weights.mean(dim=1)

if not is_batched:
    # squeeze the output if input was unbatched
    attn_output = attn_output.squeeze(1)
    attn_output_weights = attn_output_weights.squeeze(0)
return attn_output, attn_output_weights

This function returns both the O-projection (output) and the attention scores. Therefore, if you need to modify the function's return behavior, you can re-implement multi_head_attention_forward to customize the final return value, including the attention scores (attn_output_weights) as needed.
